# using **requests.get** with python to handle HTTP redirection?

Tags: python

I am having an issue with the requests module on python, when the user eneters the url on the webpage of my basic web-scraping app, then the requests module does not handle redirection [ex: http://www.yahoo.com --> ie.yahoo.com] breaking the app. Following the snippet of the code, thanks

```
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
    # the following are the data from the init form
        url = form.url.data
        email = form.email.data

        # defining a new variable taking as input the values from the init form
        mymsg=[{
            "url": url, 
            "email" : email, 
              }]
    # insert the list into the mongo db
        x = mycol.insert_many(mymsg), print("inserting this item: ", mymsg, "in the database called ", mycol)

        url1="http://"+url #making sure the parser will get the HTTP://WWW.EXAMPLE.COM syntax
        result = requests.get(url1)
        print("the requested url is: ",url1)
        print(result.status_code)            
        print(result.headers)
```

Comment: Please specify exactly what you mean by "not handle redirection". Do you mean that the requests module isn't following the redirect chain? Or that it is handling the redirect chain and you don't expect it to? My own tests show that the requests module is following the redirect chain.

Comment: sorry @tantalum I mean that the requests module isn't following the redirect chain ...   but if you say it does then I am doing something else wrong here ...

Comment: I think we need some more details to help you. `requests.get(url1)` should be querying the website and storing the response in `result`. What kind of status code and headers are you seeing?

Comment: further testing revealed that since I am doing an URL validation [not appearing the code snippet, sorry] that comes with the validators.py in the form module in python, the `url1="http://"+url ` line is messing up the format of the url, therefore I get a DNS timeout ... so redirection does not have anything to deal with this. Apologize for wasting your time